# Regex Rename with batch for files

Tags: regex, batch-file, rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I would like to rename several hundred files with a batch program. defacon to have their numbers appear first but I'm not very easy with the batch.
example of the name of my files:

```
3705_(2x).stl
68403_(4x).stl
6525_(2x).stl
22073_(3x).stl
```

to:

```
2x-3705.stl
2x-6525.stl
3x-22073.stl
4x-68403.stl
```

I have tried:

```
@echo off
set /p d=disque: // c:
set /p c=chemin: // \Users\celes\file
cls
%d%
cd%c%
set nb = findstr /r '[0-9]+x'
set p = findstr /r '[0-9]{2,}'
ren *.stl %nb%%p%.stl
pause>nul
```

Comment: The files are a lot easier to read when they are one line each.  Please do not change my edits again!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this batch file:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "*_(*).stl" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=()_" %%A in ("%%~nI") do ECHO ren "%%I" "%%B-%%A%%~xI"
pause
```

The outer **FOR** runs command **DIR** in a separate command process in background to get a list of just file names matching the pattern `*_(*).stl` which does not change during the file rename operations.

The outer **FOR** processes each file name with default behavior of splitting each line up into tokens using horizontal tabs and spaces as delimiters being disabled by specifying an empty list of delimiters.

The inner **FOR** loop processes just each file name string specified in double quotes. The command **FOR**  is instructing with the option string `tokens=1,2 delims=()_` to interpret all parentheses and underscores as delimiters and split the file name string up to at least two substrings. The first substring is the number before underscore which is assigned to specified loop variable `A`. The second substring being the string between the parentheses is assigned to next loop variable according to [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table which is the loop variable `B`.

The command **REN** executed by the inner **FOR** renames the current file as hold in loop variable `I` of outer **FOR** to new name using the two substrings determined by the inner **FOR**.

This batch file contains command **ECHO** before command `ren` to just output the rename command instead of really running it. So you can check the batch file and verify the file rename operations before really doing them. Remove command **ECHO** to really do the file renames.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `ren /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

Comment: @CelestinSv One more info: Shareware file manager Total Commander has built-in a multi-rename tool which makes file rename operations like this easy to do via a GUI which supports also Perl regular expressions for renaming files and folders. The resulting file/folder names are displayed __before__ the rename operation is executed at all. Total Commander also reports possible conflicts before doing the rename operation. And it is even possible to undo the renames on finding out after running the rename that the result is not really what you wanted.